# Find HTML radio button inside repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater

In a repeater I have following button:

```
  <input type="radio" name="mainSelection" id="rbtn" />
```

I want to check on of ratio button as True. So I am doing this `onItemDataBound` Event

How Can I find this button on the `OnItemDataBount` Event. `RepAddress_OnItemDataBound`

This is my code:

```
protected void RepAddress_OnItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
 {
  if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
   {
    // I cannot use ---> RadioButton rb = (RadioButton)e.Item.FindControl("rbtn");  
   // becuase its not an asp Radio Button.

  //I cannot use--> HtmlGenericControl rb = e.Item.FindControl("rbtn") as HtmlGenericControl;

   if (//some condition)
   {
    rb.Checked = true; // That's the reason I need to find the button.
   }
   else
   {
    rb.Checked = false;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: If you can make that radio button as server control then @RahulSingh has already given the solution. If it is must to use html radio control only, then I can show you a different approach. Let me know.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do that with pure HTML controls. It's only capable of finding server controls because they are actually present in the controls collection.

If you want you can convert your HTML radio button to server control using `runat` attribute like this:-

```
<input type="radio" runat="server" name="mainSelection" id="rbtn" />
```

After this you can find your control in `ItemDataBound` like this:-

```
HtmlInputRadioButton rb = e.Item.FindControl("rbtn") as HtmlInputRadioButton;
```